# pass html variable to angular function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a handlebar HTML variable to a scope function using Angular and if I pass using function('{{variable}}'), the value received in the function is literally {{variable}}.  If i use function({{variable}}), Angular pitches a fit.  Any ideas?

Here is the snippet..

```
<span ng-repeat="social in model.social_login">
    <button class="btn btn-{{social.network_name}} btn-sm" data-ng-show="model.credentials.network=='{{social.network_name}}'||!model.credentials.logged_in" data-ng-click="Login('{{social.network_name}}')"><i class="fa fa-{{social.network_name}}"></i> | {{model.action}} {{social.label}}</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to pass it with handlebars then... have you tried just social.network_name?

```
<button class="btn btn-{{social.network_name}} btn-sm" data-ng-show="model.credentials.network=='{{social.network_name}}'||!model.credentials.logged_in" data-ng-click="Login(social.network_name)"><i class="fa fa-{{social.network_name}}"></i> | {{model.action}} {{social.label}}</button>
```

When you pass the variable in a class, it needs to parsed for its value hence

```
class="btn brn-{{social.network_name}}"
```

if you are passing a variable to a function, no need for handlebars as it's already a scope variable and doesn't need string conversion.

```
ng-click='myFunction(social.network_name)'
```

Comment: Awesome - don't know why i had it in my head that i needed the handlebars!